# Show theme images based on the visitor's browser

Tags: themes, browser-compatibility

I'm trying to get my WordPress site to display theme images in the appropriate format based on the visitor's browser and its supported image types, such as WebP, GIF, JPEG, etc.

So far, I've tried adding this code to the end of the functions.php file in my theme:

```
// Añade soporte para el formato de imagen WebP (no es necesario si usas WordPress 5.8 o superior)
/*
function add_webp_mime_type( $mimes ) {
  $mimes['webp'] = 'image/webp';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'mime_types', 'add_webp_mime_type' );
*/

// Muestra las imágenes del tema activo en la misma carpeta que la imagen sidebar-bg.jpg
function show_theme_images() {
  // Obtiene la URL de la carpeta de imágenes del tema activo
  $theme_directory = get_template_directory_uri() . '/wp-content/';

  // Define los formatos de imagen permitidos
  $image_formats = array( 'webp', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif' );

  // Obtiene la ruta física de la carpeta de imágenes del tema activo
  $image_path = get_template_directory() . '/wp-content/';

  // Obtiene todas las imágenes válidas en la carpeta de imágenes del tema activo
  $images = get_images_in_directory( $image_path, $image_formats );

  if ( $images ) {
    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
      // Obtiene la URL y la ruta física de la imagen actual
      $image_url = $theme_directory . $image;
      $image_file = $image_path . $image;

      // Obtiene el tipo MIME de la imagen actual
      $mime_type = wp_check_filetype( $image_file )['type'];

      // Si el navegador admite el tipo MIME de la imagen actual, la muestra y sale del script
      if ( in_array( $mime_type, $image_formats ) ) {
        header( "Content-type: $mime_type" );
        readfile( $image_url );
        exit;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Obtiene todas las imágenes válidas en una carpeta dada
function get_images_in_directory( $directory, $formats ) {
  $images = array();

  if ( is_dir( $directory ) ) {
    $files = scandir( $directory );

    foreach ( $files as $file ) {
      $path = $directory . $file;
      $extension = strtolower( pathinfo( $path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

      if ( in_array( $extension, $formats ) ) {
        $images[] = $file;
      }
    }
  }

  return $images;
}

// Agrega el script que muestra las imágenes del tema activo al inicio de la ejecución de WordPress
add_action( 'init', 'show_theme_images' );
```

And I've uploaded WebP versions of the images with the same name to the theme folder where the original versions are located.

However, I haven't been able to achieve any results, and I can't figure out why. I even tried changing the image folder path to be less specific, in case that was the issue. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've provided seems to have a few issues that might be causing the problem. Here's my suggestions:

1. In WordPress, your theme's images should typically be stored in a directory within your theme's folder, not in `/wp-content/`. The `/wp-content/` directory is generally where themes, plugins, and uploads are stored, not individual images for a specific theme. You may want to create a subdirectory in your theme's directory, such as `/images/`, and store your images there. You would then adjust your `**$theme_directory**` and `**$image_path**` variables to reflect this.
2. Your `$image_formats` array seems to be holding file extensions, not MIME types. However, in your `show_theme_images()` function, you're using it to check against the MIME type of the image. You should either rename this variable to `$file_extensions` and adjust your code accordingly, or change its values to the corresponding MIME types (e.g., 'image/webp', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif').
3. Your `show_theme_images()` function is designed to send headers, which can cause issues if it's hooked into the 'init' action, because WordPress may have already started outputting the page by this point. This would result in a "headers already sent" error. A different approach is necessary to output images based on browser capabilities.

A better approach may be to use the `<picture>` element in your theme's templates, which allows you to specify multiple sources for an image and lets the browser choose the most suitable one. Here's an example:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/your-image.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/your-image.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/your-image.jpg" alt="Alt Text">
</picture>
```

In this code, the browser will try to use the WebP image first. If it can't (because it doesn't support WebP images, for example), it'll fall back to the JPEG image. The  tag is used as a final fallback for browsers that don't support the  element.

Please ensure that you replace 'your-image.webp' and 'your-image.jpg' with the correct image file names. The get_template_directory_uri() function returns the URL of the current theme, so you should place your images in the root of your theme directory (or adjust the path in the srcset attributes if you're using a subdirectory for your images).

Please note that it's crucial to keep all images optimized and to use a caching plugin to serve static images to speed up your WordPress site. Also, if your website is behind a CDN, ensure that the CDN supports these image formats.